# Need to update libconfig on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

Ubuntu 18.04 is currently at version 1.5 and I need it updated to 1.7.2. Is there a safe way to do this or should I just leave it at 1.5

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achive.

- In case it's just for you, you can try and backport 1.7.2 for youself. There are many tutorial about how to backport a package in Ubuntu or Debian. But if you did never package .DEB packages yourself, your milage may vary.
- You can (and possibly should) request an official backport using the relevant process in Ubuntu. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports in parallel. If you succeed with that, you will be able to replace your home grown backport with a backport that is available for everybody from the official repos later on.
- In case you are developing software which is supposed to get shipped and run on arbitrary machines that run 18.04, you better stick to the versions available as otherwise you will make it very complicated for users of your software to install it.